# Why http.SetCookie() isn't adding a cookie?

Tags: go

I am trying to store an id for the user when signs  in a cookie but I don't understand why the cookie isn't being set, I added the `fmt.Println("password matched")` to verify that condition is met but still the cookie isn't being set, what am I doing wrong?

```
func login(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if req.Method == http.MethodPost {
            username := req.PostFormValue("username")
            password := req.PostFormValue("password")
            if data, ok := users[username]; ok {
                if data.Password == password {
                    fmt.Println("password matched")
                    ssid, _ := uuid.NewV4()
                    mc := &http.Cookie{
                        Name:  "session",
                        Value: ssid.String(),
                        Path:  "/",
                    }
                    http.SetCookie(res, mc)
                    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "index.html", username)
                } else {
                    fmt.Fprintln(res, "Incorrect password")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the complete raw response including response headers (ideally from `curl -v`)

Comment: @zerkms curl -v localhost:8 I am getting 
https://pastebin.com/77kNheS4
not quite sure if I can send a post request using curl -v? didn't use it before

Comment: You can send any request with `-v`. Send a proper post with credentials and show the complete output.

Comment: @zerkms https://pastebin.com/sL9Bz78A

Comment: I don't see any cookies set in the response. Try a simpler example: just an endpoint that does nothing but sets a cookie.

Comment: @zerkms it's so funny that I wrote the solution here without even knowing, I change the code here from the original, before asking if request method is post I was executing a template already that was the reason it wasn't working